# How to get a response of the previous request with spring-cloud-contract

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-contract

Let's say I have a scenario that consists of 3 steps:

- Create an item.
- Update it by ID.
- Delete it by ID.

The first step is quite straightforward, I just submit a request and verify response as it's described [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/1.2.x/multi/multi__contract_dsl.html)

The problem starts with step 2. In order to perform Update and Delete I need to know the ID of the item saved in the step 1. Is there any way with spring-cloud-contracts to extract it from step 1 response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. However it seems that you're misusing the tool. You're trying to use Spring Cloud Contract for acceptance testing. Why not just set fixed values and verify the semantics?

Comment: How does this answer his question?

I mean, spring contract is used precisely to check a behavior, right? Am trying to achieve something similar and it makes perfect sense to me, I do not see what is wrong with this approach